# Checking excel specific format from input type file HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, input, types

Get the file uploaded specifically for excel only.

```
<label for="files" > </label>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" />
<input type="submit" onClick={(e)=>Upload(e) } />
```

Full control in Checking file type for specific format

Answer (score 0):

Get the file uploaded specifically for excel only.

```
<label for="files" > </label>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" />
<input type="submit" onClick={(e)=>Upload(e) } />
```

Full control in Checking file type for specific format

```
function Upload(e){
     let file = document.getElementById("files").files[0];
     if( file.type === "application/vnd.ms-excel"){
         alert("excel file");
     } 
     else{
         alert("Not Excel");
     }
}
```